# Dynamically write nginx configurations from PHP

Tags: php, security, nginx, fwrite

I am looking to write custom `nginx` directives dynamically from `PHP`. I am however concerned with security. PHP runs under the user/group `php:php` and the nginx configuration file is owned by `root:root`.

For PHP to be able to open and write to the nginx configuration file, the file needs to be owned by the user and group `php:php`.

What is the best way to do this? I suppose, I could have a secondary process in another language or PHP that actually does the read and write of the configuration files, and PHP simply talks to the secondary process.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what kind of PHP file generates the nginx. If this is a small stand-alone script, I would't have any issue with running it as root. For now I assume though that it's a php website that needs to generate and write this nginx file.

If the part that actually creates and writes the file is still rather self-contained and simple, I would make it a stand alone executable (in php, or something else), that gets some command-line parameters from the PHP website, and then `setuid` this executable (while it's owned by root). Note however that this executable should be secure: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#Security .

The alternative would be to let php write to nginx.conf (either directly, by making the file world-writable, making it group-writable and giving it a group the php user is in, or by having a separate process that copies the file from some php-written file). This is very scary though, since I'm sure that your nginx.conf file can contain commands that get executed (e.g. for authentication, or as cgi), and they will probably be executed as root (if the same config file so commands). So in this way you basically open the door for the php user to run arbitrary commands as root....

One other thing that may work (I'm not sure it's possible): You probably only want to tweak one or two parameters in the config file. See if it's possible to read just these one or two parameters from some other location (that is php writable).